# How to call Cats typeclass method without specifying it explicitly?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I want to write that code:

```scala
IO.foreverM:
  IO.sleep(1.seconds) *> IO.println("Tick")
```

But it doesn't compile. However this code compiles:

```scala
FlatMap[IO].foreverM:
  IO.sleep(1.seconds) *> IO.println("Tick")
```

Can the first one code be complied somehow?

Comment: `(IO.sleep(1.seconds) *> IO.println("Tick")).foreverM`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I know this version works, but I want to extract `foreverM` to the start of the definition

Comment: Then no, your only option would be to make `foreverM` an extension method on the `IO` companion object and that is just more trouble than worth IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IO` object doesn't contain aliases for every single typeclass operation it supports. There's no import that provides an `IO.foreverM`, though you could certainly write one, and there's been a proposal to add all such methods to the `IO` object for this reason.

In general most code you see using cats will prefer using typeclass methods on instances instead of via companion objects. Like Luis suggested in the comments, `(IO.sleep(1.seconds) *> IO.println("Tick")).foreverM`